# Como fazer uma tela de loading antes de abrir o site

Tags: php, carregamento

Olá, meu site demora **MUITO** para iniciar, muita coisa para carregar e eu gostaria de saber como fazer uma tela de Loading(como no [MEGA](https://mega.co.nz/)) enquanto o site principal carrega.

Comment: Não é melhor você identificar a causa do problema ao invés de mandar o usuário 'esperar'? No exemplo do *Mega*, o loading é pelo fato de usar javascript para montar a view - repare o source da página.

Comment: Sim, mas o site carrega uma imensa quantidade de dados, por isso a demora

Comment: Esse preload acho um tanto equivocado, toda vez que o usuário trocar de pagina seja site.com/1 para o site.com/2 o preload vai carregar novamente, isso é um tanto chato em vista de sites que tem vários "post".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você pode usar o código abaixo como modelo para montar o seu *loading*. Pode colocar uma mensagem simples como "Carregando.. Aguarde", como uma [imagem gif](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=gifs%20loading&es_sm=93&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=DGBTVYj7KcGqggTL8oHwDA&ved=0CB0QsAQ&biw=1920&bih=975) conforme simulação abaixo. Obs. coloquei o intervalo para simular, mas na prática você mudará o código .js da simulação para este (usando [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)):

```
$(window).load(function() {
     document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("conteudo").style.display = "inline";
})
```

**Simulação**

```js
var i = setInterval(function () {
    
    clearInterval(i);
  
    // O código desejado é apenas isto:
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("conteudo").style.display = "inline";

}, 4000);
```

```html
<div id="loading" style="display: block">
    <img src="http://media.giphy.com/media/FwviSlrsfa4aA/giphy.gif" style="width:150px;height:150px;" />
</div>

<!-- COLOQUE A DIV "loading" ACIMA DE TODO O CONTEUDO DO SITE (ABAIXO DA <body>) -->

<div id="conteudo" style="display: none">
  Mussum ipsum cacilds, vidis litro abertis. Consetis adipiscings elitis. Pra lá , depois divoltis porris, paradis. Paisis, filhis, espiritis santis. Mé faiz elementum girarzis, nisi eros vermeio, in elementis mé pra quem é amistosis quis leo. Manduma pindureta quium dia nois paga. Sapien in monti palavris qui num significa nadis i pareci latim. Interessantiss quisso pudia ce receita de bolis, mais bolis eu num gostis.
 </div>
```

Comment: Eu fiz isso, porem tem um problema, eu queria que ficasse um GIF aparecendo na tela enquanto o site real carregasse e nesse exemplo primeiro carrega o site, dai aparece o GIF e depois aparece o site.

Comment: @LucasCarezia verifiquei aqui em um site que tem um loading parecido com este. Você poderia testar colocando a div loading antes de todo o conteúdo do site (abaixo da <body>)?

Comment: Agora funcionou bem, porem ainda demora uns 4/5 segundos para aparecer a tela de loading

Comment: @LucasCarezia O tamanho da imagem do loading pode estar influenciando nisso, poderia fazer um teste com um texto (ex.: carregando...) e ver se ainda demora?

Comment: Diminuiu certa de 0.5 segundos o tempo

Comment: Entendo, pode ter vários fatores que influenciam nisso. Processamento do servidor, velocidade da internet, etc. Acho que não há mais nada que se possa fazer...

Comment: E caso ele esteja em um VPS com essas configurações: CPU: 2.4 GHz, RAM: 1024 MB, Espaço em Disco: 20 GB, Tráfego: 1000 GB, Mudaria muito ??

Comment: Entao, para nao extender muito nos comentários, me add no Skype que podemos conversar melhor. id: william.cspereira

Answer (score 4):

Se quiser com imagem:

jquery

```
  jQuery(window).load(function () {
      $(".loader").delay(1500).fadeOut("slow"); //retire o delay quando for copiar!
    $("#tudo_page").toggle("fast");
});
```

.css

```
.loader {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 9999;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/zAD2y29.gif') 50% 50% no-repeat white;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="loader" class="loader"></div>
<div style="display:none" id="tudo_page"> CONTEUDO DA PÁGINA <div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m7g6uq6w/

Answer (score 2):

```
<div id="content" style="display: none">
    Conteúdo da página.
</div>

<div id="loading" style="display: block">
    Loading...
</div>
```

// Só para simula atraso de carregamento.

```
var i = setInterval(function () {
    clearInterval(i);

    // O código desejado é apenas isto:
    document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";

}, 2000);
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ErickPetru/g7D8e/)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode criar uma "div" logo abaixo do "body" e realizar um "onload". Fica assim:

HTML:

```
<body onload="loading()">
    <div id="load"></div>
    ....
```

CSS:

```
#load {
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 }
```

JS:

```
function loading(){
     $('#load').css('display','none');
}
```

Com este código, assim que um usuário abrir a página, esse elemento #load ira aparecer e só ira sumir depois que toda a página for carregada através da função sendo chamada pelo "onload".

Eu estou desenvolvendo um site que contém este load com um .gif como background do elemento #load.