# Index com direcionamento de pagina home com tempo

Tags: javascript, css3, bootstrap-3

Procurei muito na web e não encontro essa duvida que tenho.

Preciso de um index.php que seja de entrada para meu site web Responsivo.

Que quando o cliente venha visitar o site eu tenha uma imagem e depois de um tempo o visitante e direcionada para meu aquivo home.php,lembrando que esse tempo tenha um gif de animação de carregamento de pagina.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63641/como-fazer-uma-tela-de-loading-antes-de-abrir-o-site

Comment: perfeito era isso mesmo que estava a procura.