# Tela de Carregamento

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, html5

estou aqui novamente.

Eu tenho uma pagina (index), que chama um javaScript, para montar um gráfico na tela, estou conseguindo, porém o gráfico está demorando um pouco para renderizar e quanto ele não renderiza a tela fica toda branca, gostaria fazer um loading, porém não estou conseguindo, tentei a solução:

[Como fazer uma tela de loading antes de abrir o site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63641/como-fazer-uma-tela-de-loading-antes-de-abrir-o-site)

Mas não obtive sucesso, na verdade o gif aparece e some muito rápido da tela e ela volta ficar branca até carregar o gráfico.

Meu html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="900">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<title>Idade</title>
 </head>
   <body> 

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div id="grafico" class="chart-container">
                <canvas id="graficoIdade"></canvas> //Lugar de renderização do grafico
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<!--Chart-->
<script src="js/graficoIdade.js"></script> //chamando o arquivo do grafico
</body>
</html>
```

Meu Js

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

      $.post({
      url:"graficos/gerarGraficoIdade.php",
      method: "POST",
      cache: false,
      success: function(idades){

        var nome = [];
        var idades = [];
        var color = [];
        var colorBorder = [];


        $.each(JSON.parse(idades), function(i, obj){
            nome.push([obj.nome]);
            idades.push(obj.idade);
            color.push('rgba(42, 99, 206, 0.2)');
            colorBorder.push('rgba(42, 99, 206, 1)');                
        });

        var ctx = document.getElementById("graficoIdade").getContext('2d');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: nome,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Idades',
                    data: idades,
                    backgroundColor: color,
                    borderColor: colorBorder,
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
            },
            options: {
                legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: 'top',
                    labels: {
                        fontColor: "#2a63ce",
                        padding: 10
                    }
                },
                responsive: true,
            }
        });
    },
    error: function() {

    }
   })
```

}); 
`

Comment: Falta o javascript para ver se estás a passar tudo direito.

Comment: Pronto, add o js!

Comment: esconda o gif somente no final das execuções do `success` em seu post... assim como no `error`

Comment: Leandro, obg deu certo!